# It's possible use Areas in Blazor Server App?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, model-view-controller, blazor, area

I'm building a solution with blazor server app, and i need to create an area like MVC application. It's possible create solution in blazor using areas?

Anyone have information or something to use for learn about it?

Comment: Chris Sainty discusses Blazor App organization in his great book, Blazor In Action. See the 18:30 mark in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k8sIIGpA3XI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want the Areas for your Blazor pages (razor components) then:  No, but you can easily use folders to achieve the same.

When you want Areas to hold razor pages (or MVC views) then create a new (scratch) Blazor server project and select Authentication=Individual accounts. That template has everything you need.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I want to "separate" the guest section, from the admin section. I Imagine, than i can have the same results using folders and roles (Microsoft Identity)

Comment: I don't think you can have an "_imports.razor" per folder, so authorization will take some care.

Comment: Ok, i understand, thanks for the information and your help (this is one of my first projects [ in blazor and web])

Comment: @HenkHolterman You definately can have an _Imports.razor per folder. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/layouts?view=aspnetcore-5.0#apply-a-layout-to-a-folder-of-components-1